# How do I have access to external java files in eclipse that are not part of the project?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, build, path

I'm about to contribute to a project that a lot of people have worked on earlier. Lets say I have this folder Hierarchy.

```
                _____C1 - ..
     ______B1--|_____C2 - ..
    |
A --|           _____C3 - ..
    |______B2--|_____C4 - ..
```

And the C- Folders contain different existing Java classes. 
Lets say I need to create my Class in folder C1, but also need to use some of the classes in the folders C2, C3, C4 .
(By using I mean "import" and use their Object instances in my Class in folder C1)

I can't seem to figure out how that works. The other folders are no eclipse projects, only folders with .java classes in it. I don't know at which point in the folder hierarchy I need to create the project so that I can have access to all the classes in Folder A, nothing seems to work.

I already tried adding folder B2 to the build path and also folder A.
Still when I'm trying to do:

import A.B2.C3.someclass;

or

import B2.C3.someclass;

it won't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself . 
Maybe this can be helpful for someone else.
I created a .jar out of folder A and added it as an external library to my Project which I created in folder C1 via
Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add external JARs

Now I can use all of the classes in A in my Project in C1.

Comment: See my answer how to do this without creating a JAR

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click project folder: ***Build Path > Configure Build Path...***
2. In the ***Projects* tab** click ***Add...*** and select the projects that should added to the build path.

See [Eclipse Help: *Java Build Path Page*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm)